# How to list down the Part of Speech and Count them?

Tags: python

I am having a problem to list down all the used POS and their count. This is my current code:

```
from nltk import word_tokenize
sentence = 'This article discusses how our evolutionary instincts clash with the modern world'
print(nltk.pos_tag(word_tokenize(sentence))))
```

Output:

```
[('This', 'DT'), ('article', 'NN'), ('discusses', 'VBZ'), ('how', 'WRB'), ('our', 'PRP$'), ('evolutionary', 'JJ'), ('instincts', 'NNS'), ('clash', 'VBP'), ('with', 'IN'), ('the', 'DT'), ('modern', 'JJ'), ('world', 'NN')
```

**My ideal output is for example:**

**NN:**

Count = 2

**DT:**

Count = 2

Also, is there a chance where it can also list down the percentage of used POS?

NN:

Percentage: 20%

Answer (score 2):

Use `collections.Counter`!

```py
>>> from collections import Counter

>>> output = [('This', 'DT'), ('article', 'NN'), ('discusses', 'VBZ'), ('how', 'WRB'), ('our', 'PRP$'), ('evolutionary', 'JJ'), ('instincts', 'NNS'), ('clash', 'VBP'), ('with', 'IN'), ('the', 'DT'), ('modern', 'JJ'), ('world', 'NN')]

>>> counter = Counter(second for first, second in output)

>>> counter
Counter({'DT': 2, 'NN': 2, 'JJ': 2, 'VBZ': 1, 'WRB': 1, 'PRP$': 1, 'NNS': 1, 'VBP': 1, 'IN': 1})

>>> counter["DT"]
2
```

Comment: Is there any way to remove the print word Counter from outputting all the list of part of speech and their count?

Comment: @Jay `counter = dict(counter)`

Comment: @Jay yes convert to dict, thats the cleanest